# Wordpress, changing the destination of the read more button

Tags: html, wordpress

How do I safely change the "read more" button's HTML to change the buttons destination page. Meaning Right now when you click my read more button it brings me to the Work page for example, but I want it to bring me to the blog page.

Comment: I think you need to сustomize excerpt_more function. You may find/write it in functions.php

Comment: Im very new to website editing. How do I do that?

Comment: could you show an HTML-code of your read more button?

Comment: <a href="http://bestdetails.com/services/detailing-services/" class="button">Read more</a>

Comment: I think this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More should help you